# Bellman-Ford Visual Example

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I'm having a really hard time visualizing how the Bellman-Ford algorithm works purely through reading code. Does anyone know of an visual example (video, slideshow) that works through an actual graph with that algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Umm.. Google? YouTube? Coursera?

Comment: Almost all of them are explaining the algorithm through code/graph notation and no one is working out a graph problem visually.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this [page](http://visualgo.net/sssp.html) might be what you are looking for. It does indeed run through the algorithm on a graph, and you may use the UI below to pause the visualization, or run through individual frames one at a time so that you can visualize it at your own pace.